# WordPress - Parse Error After Moving To New Server

Tags: php, wordpress

I just moved WordPress website from Dev Environment to Production Hosting Environment.
The first one is Windows Dev, the second is Linux Managed Hosting (only management panel + ftp).
All works as expected without sites that has in their custom code line like this:

```
<?php echo get_field_object('social')['label']; ?>
```

This code is used by plug-in Advanced Custom Fields.
On my Dev thre is no problem with this, hoverer on production I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in 
/var/sites/m/domain.name/public_html/wp-content/themes/m30pl/single-facylitator.php on line 21
```

Mentioned line is that I presented above.
I have no idea what might be wrong, on production server PHP version is 5.3.

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: The array dereferencing from function calls `get_xy("123")["key"]` does work from PHP 5.4 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

you got PHP version difference...You code will work on 5.4+ version...